# 3 Magento Servers Migrated To 1 - Product Imagery

Tags: php, rsync, magento

I recently started working for a company that sells a large amount of products online. As the business grew, instead of looking towards a more scalable solution for their hosting they have just added VPS instances with their hosting provider, created an SSH tunnel between the now three VPS machines to facilitate a local MySQL connection and assigned different domains to different VPS machines.

I've sorted out a large, scalable server that we're now migrating to and have setup the new server to be configured in the same way as the three VPS servers we have.

I had rsync'd the contents of one server's Magento installation down to my local machine, did some testing, changed some configuration options and **everything works on the new server once uploaded**. The issue that I'm having is that with some sites (there are around 15 spread across the three VPS machines), there are no product images.

I assume this is because Magento has put these product images in the file system of the server that domain is assigned to.

My question really is, is it safe to rsync the contents of ./media/catalog from each VPS server to the main server, or does Magento create a file-structure of its own and in doing that may overwrite things?

Hope you guys can point me in the right direction.

Cheers,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

I work with a similar set up. We have a minimum 3 load balanced servers that operate from one database with an SSH tunnel.

You're right about where Magento is storing the images. When Magento creates images in /magento/media/ it will create two folders with the first two characters of the filename. eg a file named "Image1.jpg" uploaded to the catalog will go to:

```
/path/to/magento/media/catalog/i/m/Image1.jpg
```

Instead of rsyncing all the other servers back, we have set up our admin area to resolve directly to the main server, and rsync the media files from the main server out to the others every 5 minutes or so.

It's not a perfect solution by any means, but it works for us at the moment. We've looked at sharing a file system between the servers, but that has it's own drawbacks.

Hope this helps.